# Unable to use shell pipe via Makefile?

Tags: shell, makefile

I have a shell command `spurious ports` which returns the following data...

```
Service                      Host                         Port   Browser link
spurious-elasticache-docker  192.168.59.103               32794  -
spurious-sqs                 sqs.spurious.localhost       32789  http://sqs.spurious.localhost:32789
spurious-s3                  s3.spurious.localhost        32790  http://s3.spurious.localhost:32790
spurious-elasticache         192.168.59.103               32793  -
spurious-dynamo              dynamodb.spurious.localhost  32791  http://dynamodb.spurious.localhost:32791
spurious-browser             browser.spurious.localhost   32795  http://browser.spurious.localhost:32795
spurious-memcached           192.168.59.103               32792  -
```

If I want to get the port number for the "dynamo" service then the following shell script works...

```
lines=`spurious ports`; echo $lines | grep "dynamo" | awk '{print $3}'
```

This retuns `32791`

But if I try and run this from inside a Makefile, I instead get the entire `spurious ports` output (all on one line?):

```
foobar:
    $(eval port:=$(shell lines=`spurious ports`; echo $$lines | grep 'dynamo' | awk '{print $3}'))
    @echo $(port)
```

I've also tried moving the commands into a shell script file:

```
#!/bin/sh
lines=`spurious ports`; echo $lines | grep "dynamo" | awk '{print $3}'
```

And inside the Makefile used:

```
PORT:=$(shell ./scripts/spurious-ports.sh)
bing:
    @echo $(PORT)
```

But this doesn't work either.

Comment: In addition you forgot to escape the `$` in the awk command; in the makefile version you need to use `awk '{print $$3}'`.  But, the whole thing of using `eval` inside a recipe is very odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems quotes issue. When you variable with multiple lines you need to put that variable in double quotes to retain the /n at end of line.

for E.g.

```
 VAR="1
 2
 3
 4"
 echo $VAR   ## here it will print "1 2 3 4"

 but echo "$VAR" will print 

 1
 2
 3
 4
```

I Think this will solve your problem. For more details read about quotes in shell.

Comment: Thank you! I shall do some reading up on how that works.